# скрипт в pycharm выключается

Tags: python

Я пишу код голосового помошника на python 3.10.5
но при запуске кода он включается пишет : Hi, PyCharm
Process finished with exit code 0

```py
    import os
    import time
    import speech_recognition as sr
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    import pyttsx3
    import datetime

    # настройки
    opts = {
        "alias": ('кеша','кеш','инокентий','иннокентий','кишун','киш',
                  'кишаня','кяш','кяша','кэш','кэша'),
        "tbr": ('скажи','расскажи','покажи','сколько','произнеси'),
        "cmds": {
            "ctime": ('текущее время','сейчас времени','который час'),
            "radio": ('включи музыку','воспроизведи радио','включи радио'),
            "stupid1": ('расскажи анекдот','рассмеши меня','ты знаешь анекдоты')
        }
    }

    # функции
    def speak(what):
        print( what )
        speak_engine.say( what )
        speak_engine.runAndWait()
        speak_engine.stop()

    def callback(recognizer, audio):
        try:
            voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = "ru-RU").lower()
            print("[log] Распознано: " + voice)

            if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
                # обращаются к Кеше
                cmd = voice

                for x in opts['alias']:
                    cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

                for x in opts['tbr']:
                    cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

                # распознаем и выполняем команду
                cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
                execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("[log] Голос не распознан!")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("[log] Неизвестная ошибка, проверьте интернет!")

    def recognize_cmd(cmd):
        RC = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
        for c,v in opts['cmds'].items():

            for x in v:
                vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
                if vrt > RC['percent']:
                    RC['cmd'] = c
                    RC['percent'] = vrt

        return RC

    def execute_cmd(cmd):
        if cmd == 'ctime':
            # сказать текущее время
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            speak("Сейчас " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))

        elif cmd == 'radio':
            # воспроизвести радио
            os.system("D:\\Jarvis\\res\\radio_record.m3u")

        elif cmd == 'stupid1':
            # рассказать анекдот
            speak("Мой разработчик не научил меня анекдотам ... Ха ха ха")

        else:
            print('Команда не распознана, повторите!')

    # запуск
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    m = sr.Microphone(device_index = 1)

    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

    speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

    # Только если у вас установлены голоса для синтеза речи!
    voices = speak_engine.getProperty('voices')
    speak_engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

    # forced cmd test
    speak("Мой разработчик не научил меня анекдотам ... Ха ха ха")

    #speak("Добрый день, повелитель")
    #speak("Кеша слушает")

    #stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
    #while True: time.sleep(0.1) # infinity loop
```

Comment: может вы посоветуете способ запуска кода так чтобы он работал в фоне?

Comment: Всë верно, код завершается с кодом 0, то есть без ошибок, потому что вы ничего не запустили, никакого цикла нет

Comment: Бесконечный цикл, кстати, решит вашу проблему с работой в фоне

Comment: Так Вы же закомментировали строки -
#speak("Добрый день, повелитель")
#speak("Кеша слушает")

#stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
#while True: time.sleep(0.1) # infinity loop

Comment: #speak("Добрый день, повелитель") #speak("Кеша слушает") #stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback) #while True: time.sleep(0.1) # infinity loop ( я случайно их тут закоментирывал код всеровно останавливается в pycharm